# Logging python изменение формата отдельного вывода

Tags: python, логирование

Имеется большая программа с настроенным логированием. Как можно изменить формат в одном из информационных выводов?

```
    FORMAT = FORMAT = '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] process: %(process)d'  / 
             ' - %(message)s   in %(module)s - %(funcName)s. '
    formatter = logging.Formatter(FORMAT)
    .....
    logger = logging.getLogger("...")
    .....
    def log_subprocess_output(pipe):
        for line in iter(pipe.readline, b''):  # b'\n'-separated lines
            logger.info(line.decode('utf-8'))
```

Есть функция `log_subprocess_output()`, которая выводит логи некоторых других процессов. Проблема в том, что они дублируются с общим форматом (время /уровень, а остальная информация вовсе тут не нужна).

Как можно в это конкретном месте задать формат `(message)s`? Пока на ум приходит отдельно котрыть запись в файл и принт в stdout, а хотелось бы использовать logging.

Answer (score 0):

ВЫ можете переопределять формат логирования на время, предварительно сохранив оригинальный формат и затем вернув его:

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
logger.addHandler(logger_handler)

# создаем основной формат логирования:
logger_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('original %(message)s'))

def myfunc():
    # сохраняем основной формат:
    oldfmt = logger.handlers[0].formatter._fmt
    # создаем новый:
    logger_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('¯\_(ツ)_/¯ modified %(message)s'))
    # пишем лог в новом формате:
    logger.error('error message')
    # восстанавливаем старый формат:
    logger_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(oldfmt))

# пишем в лог в старом формате
logger.error('error message')
# пишем в лог в формате, определенном в функции:
myfunc()
# снова пишем в лог в старом формате:
logger.error('error message')
```

Результат логирования со сменой форматов:

```
original error message
¯\_(ツ)_/¯ modified error message
original error message
```